# Convert HTML entities to characters, or display the hrefs

Tags: html, code-conversion

I need a perl command or other way to replace HTML entities, some hex, some decimal and some named with the actual characters, OR a browser setting or tool that will show the href next to the rendering of a link.

It's a page with a char set tag for UTF-8, but all the non-ASCII characters are entities, mostly numeric, and many of the Chinese words are links to sound files with ASCII file names.  So when I look at the browser, I see the Chinese, and when I look at the HTML, I see only the file names.  I've spent a LONG time trying to match the two and getting lots of them wrong.

Comment: Duh!!  One way, which didn't occur to me till after posting, is to just copy the filename for each link to immediately after the link's close tag, then reload the page.  But if there's a better way, please answer.

Comment: My regex for doing that didn't work, but just as easy was to removed the link tags.  The conversion of entities would still be nice to know, though.